# Need help conditionally including php in page

Tags: php, if-statement, include

I've been trying to conditionally include a banner which incorporates a form into a php site. Previously the banner was part of the header but I need to exclude it from certain pages in order for other elements to be included.

I'm using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to define a variable on the page and then check for this. I'm a little confused though as to where the variable should be placed. Will it work if placed in the header or does it need to be included in every separate page?

This is what I've got:

```
<?php $currentPage = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>    
<?php if ($currentPage != "/ecoProcess.php") {
include ("includes/banner.php");
 } else {
echo "ECO";
 }
 ?>
```

For further info, I've updated the code because of my schoolboy error with -= instead of != but neither of the conditions works now (no banner, no "ECO"). The pages are being called using this method:

```
    <?php if($_GET['action']=='boiler_installation_replacement') {?> class="active"<? php } ?>><a href="index.php?action=boiler_installation_replacement&src=<?php echo $_GET['src']; ?>">Boiler Installation and Replacement</a>
```

I've been advised to try var_dump which reveals this:

' string(14) "/ths/index.php" ' everytime. I guess this is due to the way the pages are called but I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: `if ($currentPage -= "/ecoProcess.php")` what is it.. i guess you need `if ($currentPage == "/ecoProcess.php")` .

Comment: Either that or if you want all pages **except** ecoProcess, then you need to use ``!=`` which stands for not equal to. As for your question in general, yes you can include conditionally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've changed it to be not equal (a schoolboy error!) but it's still not doing anything. Even the else part doesn't work now. Is it correct to place this statement in the 'header.php' file? Basically the banner should be on all pages but NOT the ecoProcess page.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem placing in the header.php file, since you're using ``$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`` which is a global variable. But what do you mean the else part doesn't work? Is it not showing "ECO" when you view other pages?

Comment: That's right, it's not showing. Obviously the echo statement is just a placeholder for now but as I said, it's stopped showing on ALL pages. I don't suppose it would return an error if the filepath was incorrect?

Comment: Do you mean that header.php stopped showing in all other pages? If so, can you update your question to show what you have right now? (I still see ``-=``)

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the word 'ECO' had stopped showing. Basically as I've updated above, due to the way the pages are called, it seems as if index.php loads in the other page parts. I'm totally out of my depth here but it seemed pretty straightforward(!)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally figured it. Back to the manual methinks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-=` means subtract right value from left side. Eg.

```
$a = 5;
$a -= 3;
echo $a; // will print 2 because 5 - 3 = 2 :)
```

Change it to comparison `==` or better `===`. You can also use `!=`/ `!==` for opposite cases.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to != but now it's not doing anything at all. Previously at least it always returned "ECO".

Comment: @user2739763 It'll always execute one or other statement. There is no other option. Check `$currentPage` with `var_dump()`.

Comment: Thanks. var_dump returns string(14) "/ths/index.php" everytime. I guess this is due to the way the pages are called but I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: @user2739763 So you have to check for actions, not for script file.

Comment: Forgive me, I don't know how to go about that at all. Would it be something like: if (action='ecoProcess') ??

Comment: @user2739763 Depends, how do you checking which file to load now?

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition like this.

```
<?php 
 $currentPage = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];     
 if ($currentPage == "/ecoProcess.php") {
     include ("includes/banner.php");
 } else {
    echo "ECO";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

just change your if statement because it is not logically correct.

Use this

```
if ($currentPage == "/ecoProcess.php")
```

instead of

```
if ($currentPage -= "/ecoProcess.php")
```

Thanks